# Добавление базы данных sqlite при сборке проекта

Tags: java, база-данных, maven, sqlite3

Вопрос таков,собрал проект с помощью мавен,получился jar with dependencies,из консоли intellej idea jar  запускается и отлично работает.Из обычной виндовской консоли или  Gitbush ругается что не может найти базу данных .база данных лежит в папке src.
может надо куда то в другое место ее положить и пересобрать проект ,или какие то хитрости в pom.хмl дописать?

вот что пишет

```
$ java -jar Tbot-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
java.sql.SQLException: path to 'src\userDate.db': 'D:\farcry\javabegin\spring_osnovy\5\Tbot\target\src' does not exist
        at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:215)
        at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:61)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:28)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:21)
        at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:116)
        at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:90)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at Bdate.<init>(Bdate.java:9)
        at Botstart1.<init>(Botstart1.java:19)
        at Bt.main(Bt.java:23)
```

сама програмаа работает ,но в базу из базы данных не записывает и не выдает

Comment: Код использования БД покажите.

Comment: Вообщем ошибку победил .просто нужно указать полный путь до файла базы данных в коде java и приложение начинает работать из консоли без использования интеледжа.